# Spring Integration - passing json parameters to HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I want to pass json parameters in the URL of rest API with SI - HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.

This is the Controller ---

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class NotificationController {

    @Autowired
    NotificationGateway notificationGateway;
    
    
    @PostMapping
    @RequestMapping("/sendmsg")
    public String sendMsg(@RequestBody SMSData smsData) {
        return notificationGateway.sendMsg(smsData);
    }
}
```

This is the Gateway ---

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface NotificationGateway {


    @Gateway(requestChannel = "httpOutRequest")
    public String sendMsg(SMSData smsData);
}
```

This is the Service ---

```
@Configuration
public class HTTPConfig {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HTTPConfig.class);

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "httpOutRequest")
    public MessageHandler outbound() {
        log.info("Inside HTTPConfig :: outbound() invoked ");
        HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(
                "http://localhost:9090/Gateway/rest?msg={msg}&mobileNo={mobileNo}", restTemplate());
        handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
        handler.setExpectedResponseType(String.class);
        handler.setExpectReply(true);

        ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        handler.setUriVariableExpressions(
                Collections.singletonMap("msg", expressionParser.parseExpression("headers['msg']")));
        handler.setUriVariableExpressions(
                Collections.singletonMap("mobileNo", expressionParser.parseExpression("headers['mobileNo']")));
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
        log.info("Inside HTTPConfig :: restTemplateBuilder() invoked ");
        return new RestTemplateBuilder();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        log.info("Inside HTTPConfig :: restTemplate() invoked ");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

This is the DTO---

```
public class SMSData {

    public String msg;
    public String mobileNo; 
    
}
```

Please help with how to pass parameters in outbound()
JSON ---
{"msg" : "This is my message",
"mobileNo" : "00123456987"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract is this `public String sendMsg(SMSData smsData);`, but then you try to pass into request params from headers: `headers['msg']` and `headers['mobileNo']`.
If you say that your `SMSData` contains all the info, then you need to make those expressions against payload: `payload['msg']` and `payload['mobileNo']`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks Artem, 
Can u please help how can i send custom http headers (key-value) in same request?

Comment: You need to supply them in the request message upfront, then configure a `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.setHeaderMapper()` to map them into an HTTP request. See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/http.html#http-header-mapping

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share a annotation based snippet.

Comment: HeaderMapper<HttpHeaders> headerMapper = new DefaultHttpHeaderMapper();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("Header-1", "Value-1");
        httpHeaders.add("Header-2", "Value-2");
        headerMapper.toHeaders(httpHeaders);
        handler.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper);

I added this, but doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure what you show. See the docs: you nee to provide a `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` with `thing1, thing2, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS` header patterns into your `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` definition. The message you send to the `httpOutRequest` must have those custom headers. The `headerMapper.toHeaders()`  is called by the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`. However that is still wrong. The`fromHeaders()` is used when we perform an HTTP request.

Comment: Why do you talk about an "annotation snippet" since you have a plain Java configuration: `new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler()`. That's why I suggest you that `setHeaderMapper()`. You probably also miss the fact that there is a configuration phase for those components and runtime when the framework reacts to messages sent to the service activator input channel.